# Benchmark Video Meta Testing Framework

Tags: test-automation-framework, jenkins, testing-framework

I’m trying to find a good flow/framework to perform benchmark tests.

I have a video transcoder CLI app which get as an input a video and output a video.
I need to write a script which will compare output metadata for a specific Pull Request (for example: size of the video, number of frames,…) with the master branch

Example: `assert sizeFeature == sizeMaster`

In addition and in the future, I would also need to add a percentage variable to be considered as OK.

Example: `assert sizeFeature between sizeMaster*0.9 and sizeMaster*1.1`

Is there a testing framework which could help me implement this use case?

Comment: There are plenty that will work with Jenkins, avoid technology proliferation, your first candidate should be the existing technology stack used by the application.  e.g. If Java then JUnit.